# Comparing performances of different models using hypothesis testing

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

A common workflow in applied ML is you train different models on some data and evaluate it on a particular test set. I have often seen people just selecting a ML metric based on their requirements and choosing ML models on the basis of that.

But is the above process right ? Shouldn't we be ideally doing hypothesis testing and arriving at statistical and practical significance before saying `model A > model B` simply based on ML metric calculated on a common test set

Comment: This can be done in certain instances, such as when you are predicting the percentage correct between test and train and you might use a chi-square test.  But you are correct, their are a lot of different measures, and hypothesis testing is more or less reserved for data which meets some good assumptions.  In ML often the goal is optimization which is different from hypothesis testing.

Comment: @RalphWinters - thanks for commenting, True in ML - our goal is optimization but i am question is post optimization phase. Let's say youve optimized 2 models and A has 88% f score and B has 90% on the same test set- should i just conclude B is better than A just based on f1 score.

Comment: Well yes, if you want to use one metric (and the difference is very small).  However you should understand that F combines precision and recall into one metric.  You should look at them both separately and decide which one is more important

Comment: @RalphWinters - yes, i am aware f1 combines precision and recall - it is basically a harmonic mean of both the metrics. Above was just an example  i wanted to put forward wrt my question :)

Comment: My first intuition is let's say we test the 2 models on 1000 samples where model A and B get 700 and 800 correct respectively, a typical 2-sample t-test can tell if a model is better (at some CI).